# Any python linter to warn var shadow argument

Tags: python, lint, pylint, pyflakes

pylint(1.5.2) says "Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)", this is absolutely not the case. Any lint tool to warn about this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''test module'''


def test_fn(var_arg):
    '''test_fn'''
    for var_arg in [1, 2]:
        print var_arg


def main():
    '''main'''
    test_fn(3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Have you tried PyChecker? http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I am afraid `pylint`, `flake8` or the built-in  `pycharm` code analysis tool are not gonna handle this case.

Comment: @alecxe The built-in `pycharm` static analysis tool won't do this? I thought it at least gave a warning for shadowing? Or is the warning only for shadowing built-in functions? If this is the case, I'm afraid PyChecker may be the same.

Comment: @MichaelRecachinas I'm afraid so, PyCharm has this `Shadowing names from outer scope`, but this is not exactly what is happening here..I guess a custom lint rule is the way to go.

Comment: pylint, as pycharm, warns on shadowing from outer scope, but function's argument are in the function scope. You may submit a feature request on https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues

Answer (score 0):

There are many great comprehensive python linting tools besides pylint that you might want to check out:

- Pycodechecker (https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle): compares your code to the PEP8 guidelines
- PyChecker (http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/)

Also, you should check out some of the linters from this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/a/7925369/4698963